# Producing a 3D Net from a 3d inspired image

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, 3d, volume

Producing a 3D Net from a 2D Image

I'm trying to find the volume of the illustration, I've taken reference from the medium size of a strawberry's diameter, I've applied this scale to the remaining sides of the shape. As for the image, it's the only reference I have to work from. Ultimately I'm trying to produce a net, the  image has been created / drawn to resemble a '3d' looking object, I'm trying to convert the image back into a 3d net. And to find the volume of the illustrated components Cake Sponge, Icing, Strawberry, Cake Filling Etc.[image]

Comment: Here are some questions, in an attempt to make this question more comprehensible. The illustration is 2-dimensional. You're asking for the volume of the 3-dimensional thing it illustrates, right? The strawberry has an irregular shape so there will be no "formula" for its volume: you have told us the "length" and "width" of the strawberry but I'm not sure that has any meaning. How accurate does the formula have to be? Are the sides of the cake completely vertical? What is the thickness of the icing on the top? We can see 4 strawberries inside the cake. Are there any more?

Comment: Thank you for your response - Yes correct. Needs to be within 0.1mm. That's where the main problem lies, is within the off angle sides and being unable to calculate them. So the side aren't completely vertical. There are no strawberries inside the cake just red filling.

Comment: I would venture that it is impossible to find the volume of a strawberry to that accuracy unless you have really precise formulae for the curves that make it up. As for the other stuff, if the sides aren't completely vertical then for a first approximation why not cut the shape up into tetrahedrons and just compute their volumes using standard formulae. But to be honest with something this complex you might just be better off making a model of it in a mathematical software program and letting it do the heavy lifting for you. I had no idea the sides weren't straight. This q is a nightmare.